# Regular expression can't match multiple groups of the same type

Tags: python, regex

I'm playing with Regex's in python. I know there is a ton of documentation on this. But I just can't understand this apparently simple example:

On this code:

```
import re
phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'(\d\d\d)*')
mo = phoneNumRegex.search('My number is 415-555-4242. 423-531-5412')
print(mo.group())
```

I'm expecting to get the output:

```
415, 555, 423, 531
```

However the program only returns an empty string(nothing). My logic was to specify that I want a group of 3 digits and then the `*` specifies to match this kind of group **0** or **'n'** times. Since I have multiple 3 digit groups in my string I was expecting to get all of them printed. What am I doing wrong?I tried with the `+` as well instead of `*` which by my understanding is supposed to find the group at least once. If I do that it only prints the first group and not all as I would expect. How should I write this to get all 3 digit groups printed?

Comment: Use `re.findall`

Comment: You've written something that will return the first match. The first match for `(\d\d\d)*` is an empty string, so you get an empty string. Use `findall` without the `*`.

Comment: your problem is that `search` returns the very first match. And because `(\d\d\d)*` matches an empty string, it returns an empty string. As said before, use `findall` instead.

Comment: Did any of the answers help or do you need more assistance with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Use `re.findall`

**Ex:**

```
import re
phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'(\b\d{3}\b)')
mo = phoneNumRegex.findall('My number is 415-555-4242. 423-531-5412')
print(mo)
```

**Output:**

```
['415', '555', '423', '531']
```

Comment: I know about findall. But I want to know what's wrong with my regex and why is not working as I was expecting it to :D

Answer (score 2):

You have defined a [**repeated capturing group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html). The `(\d\d\d)*` pattern matches and captures into a capturing group with ID 1 any 3 digits, *zero* or more times (due to the `*` quantifier), that is, if there is no digit at a certain location inside the string, an empty string will be captured, and if there are 6 consecutive digits, it will match them all, but the capturing group memory buffer will contain the last 3. See [your pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJ8cqM/1) with *multiple matching* enabled.

However, in your code, you are using [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search), a method that *only returns a single (the first) match*. Since the engine tries to match a string from left to right, it checks the starting position and finds `M`. It is not a digit, so the pattern matches an empty string before `M` (due to `*` quantifier).

So, if you use `re.findall`, you will get many empty strings inside the resulting list using the pattern.

As a quick fix you would use `+` quantifier, 1 or more repetitions, but it would still return 3 digit chunks located at the end of each digit chunks.

The solution is to use a *multiple matching* method, like [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) or [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) without an enclosing quantified grouping construct, `r'\d{3}'`, or in case you need to match a 3-digit number not enclosed with other digits, `r'(?<!\d)\d{3}(?!\d)'` or `r'\b\d{3}\b'` to match the 3-digit chunks as a whole word. See a [sample regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJ8cqM/2).